# Error In Azure: Could not load file or assembly NuGet.Core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, runtime

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Core, Version=1.6.30117.9648, Culture=neutral,  
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's  
manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

How Could I solve this problem? And.Next Text Error:

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value..[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

From the stack Trace:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Core,   
Version=1.6.30117.9648, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of  
its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the  
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
```

This is my first project in Azure. I have no idea what to do. 
Thank you for your consideration!

**UPD:
It seems Like I have mismathes in my project.. For instance in Error: "NuGet.Core, Version=1.6"  In my programm's referances it is Version=2.6 and in "packages.config" the same 2.6 version. Where could I change this error?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks less like an Azure problem and more like a Visual Studio problem.  If you have a project with NuGet referenced, remove it.  NuGet should be integrated into VS and not into your project.  Then update your version of NuGet.

In Visual Studio 2012:

> Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings ->
>   Package Manager -> Package Sources and click Update.

The source would be https://nuget.org/api/v2/

Comment: I am using VS 2013 that is already using nuget V2. Website works on my local dev machine and on my local IIS. But When I publish to Azure free website I get an error saying `Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Core, Version=1.6.30117.9648, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Any ideas about how to fix it? I can't even figure out what the problem is and why it needs Nuget.Core

Comment: @ToKa it sounds very similar to the problem that OP had.  Do you have nuget referenced in your project?  Also, that version is very out of date, following these instructions should get you fixed.

Comment: @paqogomez Thank you for a prompt answer. Yes I do have Nuget References.It is a WebAPI project with some Razor components. Which instructions to you mean? I have VS 2013, there is no Library Package Manager, There is NuGet Package Manager and is already referencing v2 API.

Comment: `If you have a project with NuGet referenced, remove it.`

Comment: @paqogomez I don't have a reference of NuGet itself. I only have the references of minimal required packages for Razor and WebAPI to work: 
* Antlr
* Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
* Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
* Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
* Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
* Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
* Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
* Newtonsoft.Json
* WebGrease

Comment: @ToKa Razor and WebAPI do not *require* Nuget, they are installed *by* nuget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68363/discussion-between-to-ka-and-paqogomez).

Comment: Well, I ended up creating a brand new project, copying all code files from the old file and now it magically works :)

Comment: @ToKa, I'm sure you'll find that you no longer have project references to Nuget.  Glad we got you to a solution. Dont forget the upvotes.